SwiftUI Toolbar on Keyboard not shown at first time
When I open my new page, and then select TextField keyboard open but toolbar with done button not shown. After I took my app background mode to foreground mode toolbar with done button shown.
This is my simple code.
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 40)
            .padding(.all)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Done") {
                        isFocused = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }

This is the situation Link
I try everything,
Put it my textfield on VStack call toolbar in vstack, I put every where but same problem.

I believe this is another SwiftUI bug. Mine toolbar doesn't show up in iOS 17. You can try this workaround, wrapping content inside a NavigationStack.
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        TextField...
    }
}

